# Array with too many elements only compiler warning?

Tags: ada

I created the following example:

```ada
procedure Example is
   type Index_Type is range 1 .. 3;

   type Array_Type is array (Index_Type) of Integer;
   
   Array_Fail_One : Array_Type := (11, 22, 33, 44);
   Array_Fail_Two : Array_Type := (1 => 11, 2 => 22, 3 => 33, 4 => 44);
begin
   null;
end Example;
```

Why is thind kind of problem only treated as a warning and not as an error?

```
example.adb:6:35: warning: upper bound of aggregate out of range
example.adb:6:35: warning: Constraint_Error will be raised at run time
example.adb:7:35: warning: upper bound of aggregate out of range
example.adb:7:35: warning: Constraint_Error will be raised at run time
```

Comment: For guaranteeing absence of runtime errors, see SPARK. See also -Werror

Comment: Actually `-gnatwe` (treat warnings as errors)

Comment: For reference, `-Werror` "causes warnings from the GCC back end to be treated as errors." `-gnatwe` "causes warning messages and style check messages to be treated as errors."

Answer (score 3):

It is a warning because the compiler detected a run time error which will result in the exception Constraint_Error to be raised.

The Ada compiler does not guarantee absence of all run time errors, but it does flag those errors it detects.